# Constructor cannot use make_shared<T>()

Tags: c++, constructor

I must be mistaken about something in the following code. I was experimenting, and couldn't understand why the `make_shared` cannot be called in the constructor, where as in `initialize()`, it works fine

```
class A {
public:
    A() {
        here = make_shared<A>();
    }
    void initialize(){
//      here = make_shared<A>();
        cout << &*here << endl;
        cout << &here << endl;
    }
    void hereAddress() {
        cout << &*here << endl;
    }
private:
    shared_ptr<A> here;
};

int main(){
    vector<shared_ptr<A> > myA;
    cout << "hi" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; ++i) {
        myA.push_back(make_shared<A>() );
    }

    for (const auto& i : myA) {
        i->initialize();
        i->hereAddress();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this, I get exitcode -1. I appreicate your help.

Comment: A's constructor uses make_shared which creates new A object which involves calling A's constructor... - infinite recurrence.

Comment: @navyblue that would have been an answer... I guess it was a trivial question to you. thanks

Comment: on a note... you might be interested in `std::shared_from_this`

Answer (score 0):

This is because `here = make_shared();` is invoking class constructor
and calling it inside constructor will make recursive calls to constructor causing segmentation faults 
We need to call it outside constructor to avoid compiler complains.

Comment: The compiler probably won't complain about this problem. More likely the program will act nasty when you try to run it.